# How to deal with multiple categorical variables each with different cardinality?

Tags: random-forest, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I’m working with an auto dataset I found on kaggle. Besides numerical values like horsepower, car length, car weight etc., it has multiple categorical variables such as:

1. car type (sedan, suv, hatchback etc.): cardinality=5
2. car brand (toyota, Nissan, bmw etc.): cardinality=21
3. Doors (2door and 4door): cardinality=2
4. Fuel type (gas and diesel): cardinality =2

I would like to use a random forest classifier to perform feature selection with all these variables as input. I’m aware that the categorical variables need to be encoded before doing so. What is the best approach to handling data with such varying cardinalities?

Can I apply different encoding techniques to different variables? Say for example, one hot encoding on fuel type and label encoding on car type?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* apply different encoding techniques to different variables. However, label encoding introduces hierarchy/order, which doesn't look appropriate for any of the predictors you mention. For this example it looks like one-hot-encoding all the categorical predictors would be better, unless there are some ordinal variables you haven't mentioned.

EDIT: in response to your comment. I would only ever use label encoding if a categorical predictor was ordinal. If they aren't, I would not try and enforce it, and would use one-hot-encoding if the model type couldn't cope with categorical predictors. Whether this causes an issue regarding sparse trees and too many predictors depends entirely on your dataset. If you still have many rows compared to predictors then it generally isn't a problem. You can run into issues with random forests if you have a lot of predictors that aren't correlated at all with the target variable. In this case, as predictors are chosen randomly, you can end up with lots of trees that don't contain any relevant predictors, creating noise. In this case you could try and remove non-relevant predictors before running the random forest model. Or you could try using a different type of model, e.g. penalized regression.

Comment: Thank you. Yes label encoding was just used as an example to describe my case. However, won’t one hot encoding all variables result in a very sparse tree?

Comment: @Kristi I added some more to my answer - hope this answers your question :-)